# Prevent "order by" clause in Ebean

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

Ebean ORM adds `sort by t0.id` clause to every query and it leads to very very bad performance.

I use Play Framework 2.6, H2 1.4 database and Ebean 11.15 (PlayEbean 4.1.3). I have a table with 100k rows and it grows lager.

I have several schedules tasks which select a batch of records from the table and process data, and order doesn't matter.

So for example I use this query:

```java
Chunk.find.query()
        .select("id, lat, lon, data, status")
        .fetch("area", "id, polygon")
        .setMaxRows(100)
        .where()
            .eq("status", 0)
        .query()
        .findList();
```

Then Eben generates and executes this:

```sql
select 
  c.id,
  c.lat,
  c.lon,
  c.data,
  c.status,
  a.id,
  a.polygon
from chunk c
join area a on a.id = c.area_id 
where c.status = 0
order by c.id
limit 100;
```

It would be superb to have no `order by c.id`.

If i execute the query manually it will take ~5000 ms. But if I remove the `order by` clause it will take ~10 ms only! And there's so much places in my appication where I do not need sorting and it could work a lot faster.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ebean, try to post here, this is the main ebean-related questions forum, overseen by the developers of ebean.

Comment: Hi @Aunmag , have you progressed?

Comment: Hi @rob-bygrave, yes. The only solution for now is to add `.orderBy("status")`

Comment: Why do you restrict number of rows with setMaxRows(100) and don't want any ordering? Would you like to have random 100 rows or you expect that db will supply some default order? Will you retrieve next page with 100 rows at some time?

Comment: findNative() would also work.   Given the 'several schedules tasks which select a batch of records from the table and process data' ... I'd almost expect a "partial index" on the status column and a updateSkipLocked() on the query (depending on the production db being used).

Comment: @jnr, it's ok to have random 100 rows, then sleep for a while and repeat query

Comment: @Aunmag Did you ask the Ebean developers for other options or an enhancement as suggested by Bon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution for now is to use `.orderBy("1")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .orderById(false) with the version of Ebean you're using. This was added in [11.12.1](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/releases/tag/ebean-11.12.1)

```
Chunk.find.query()
    .select("id, lat, lon, data, status")
    .fetch("area", "id, polygon")
    .setMaxRows(100)
    .where()
        .eq("status", 0)
    .query()
    .orderById(false)
    .findList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the method has not effect. I still see `ORDER BY id` in SQL logs.